# Waiting on multiple signals - pthread

Tags: pthreads

I am building a simple job system that would allow me to create a job graph with dependencies... Something like:

```
Job root;
Job job1;
Job job1_1;
Job job1_2;
Job job2(&job1, 1); // job2 cannot start until job1 finishes.

job1.addJob(&job1_1);
job1.addJob(&job1_2);
root.addJob(&job1);
root.addJob(&job2);

root.execute(); // execute the job graph.
```

I am using pthreads to implement this but I am new to this type of programs and I cant find a way to synchronize all this.

I tried using pthread_join to do something like this :

```
void Job::execute()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numDependencies; ++i)
        dependencies[i].join(); // calling pthread_join

    for(int i = 0; i < numSubJobs; ++i)
        subJobs[i].start(); // calling pthread_create

    ... do some work here

    for(int i = 0; i < numSubJobs; ++i)
        subJobs[i].join(); // calling pthread_join
}
```

But my program crash in one of the pthread_join call.

> From the pthread documentation :
>
> The results of multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join()
> specifying the same target thread are undefined.

How can I achieve the same results but without the crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**pthred_join()** waits for created thread termination. And program crashes because you are using uninitialized members of Job (let's say pthread_t thread; ). If job thread is created in start() method, then you should rewrite execute() as:

```
void Job::execute()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numDependencies; ++i)
        dependencies[i].start(); // calling pthread_create

    for(int i = 0; i < numDependencies; ++i)
        dependencies[i].join(); // calling pthread_join
...
```

You will not get *multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread* in this case (and moreover this was not an issue in your case also).